# Access elements of returned array in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, element

How does one access an element of an array that is returned from a function? For example, `shape()` returns an array of integers. How does one compare an element of that array to an integer? The following does not compile:

```
integer :: a
integer, dimension(5) :: b

a = 5
if (a .eq. shape(b)) then
    print *, 'equal'
end if
```

The error is:

```
if (a .eq. shape(c)) then
    1
Error: IF clause at (1) requires a scalar LOGICAL expression
```

I understand that this is because `shape(c)` returns an array. However, accessing an element of the array does not appear to be possible like so: `shape(c)(1)`

Now if I add these two lines:

```
integer, dimension(1) :: c
c = shape(b)
```

...and change the `if` clause to this:

```
if (a .eq. c(1)) then
```

... then it works. But do I really have to declare an extra array variable to hold the return value of `shape()`, or is there some other way to do it?

Comment: If your array always starts at 1, you could use ubound(b,1).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Further to the answers that deal with SHAPE and logical expressions etc, the general answer to your question "How does one access an element of an array that is returned from a function?" is

- you assign the expression that has the function reference to an array variable, and then index that array variable.
- you use the expression that has the function reference as an actual argument to a procedure that takes a dummy array argument, and does the indexing for you.

Consequently, the general answer to your last questions "But do I really have to declare an extra array variable to hold the return value of shape(), or is there some other way to do it?" is "Yes, you do need to declare another array variable" and hence "No, there is no other way".

(Note that reasonable optimising compilers will avoid the need for any additional memory operations/allocations etc once they have the result of the array function, it's really just a syntax issue.)

The rationale for this particular aspect of language design is sometimes ascribed to a need to avoid syntax ambiguity and confusion for array function results that are of character type (they could potentially be indexed and/or substringed - how do you tell what was intended?).  Others think it was done this way just to annoy C programmers.

Comment: This does answer the real question about Fortran style, so I'm accepting this as the answer. However, @SuperCow and @cup both fixed my short-term problem by recommending `size` or `ubound` with the `dim` attribute specified. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using `shape(array)`, I would use `size(array)`.

Note that this will return an integer indicating how many elements there are in ALL dimensions, unless you specify the `DIM` attribute, in which case it will return only the number of elements in the specified dimension.

Take a look at the gfortran documentation:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SIZE.html.

Also, look up `lbound` and `ubound`.

Comment: `size` and `ubound` both appear to work great for me when I supply the `dim` parameter. I appreciate the tips!

Answer (score 2):

Note that the expression

```
a == shape(b)
```

returns a rank-1 array of logicals and the `if` statement requires that the condition reduce to a scalar logical expression.  You could reduce the rank-1 array to a scalar like this:

```
if (all(a == shape(b)))
```

This is certainly not a general replacement for the syntactically-invalid application of array indexing to an array-returning function such as `shape(b)(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible even without the intermediate variable using `ASSOCIATE`:

```
 real c(3,3)
 associate (x=>shape(c))
   print *,x(1),x(2)
 end associate
end
```